# Excel - SUMIFS over a set

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs

I am trying to use a sumif where the criteria is that column B equals 1 or 11:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,{1,11})
```

The formula above works perfectly. But now what I would like to do is store {1,11} in a cell (e.g. cell C1). Then:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,C1)
```

This no longer works, and it seems to pull up C1 as "{1,11}". Even though there are no visible quotes in cell C1, when I highlight C1 and press F9 in the sumif formula, quotes do come up.

Is there any way to do this? I want to be able to set the array {1,11} as a variable in a separate cell, because this could change. I do not want it hardcoded within the sumifs formula.

Thanks!!

Comment: `=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,{1,11})` should not work,  it should be `=SUM(SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,{1,11}))` otherwise it is only returning the `1` and not the `11`.

Comment: As to your question, you can't.  You can put 1 in C1 and 11 in C2 and use: `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,C1:C2))`

Comment: That's very helpful - thanks! Any recommendations if the length of C1:C2 needs to be dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your desired lookup in C1 and down, this is dynamic

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,C1:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1E+99,C:C))))
```

Just make sure there are no other numbers in column C and the list is contiguous.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is you can use text in C1:

```
'{1,11}
```

And then define a name to convert it to an array:

`EvalC1` refers to

```
=EVALUATE($C$1)
```

Note you can use the name in your array formula:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,EvalC1)
```

Comment: Your formula needs to be `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,EvalC1))` entered normally or `=SUM(SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,EvalC1))` entered as an array or it will only pick up the first in the array.

Comment: @ScottCraner Just copying the formula in the original question - and you are right, that seems invalid.

Comment: But, that formula is in error.  And propagating the error in an answer will lead future viewers down the wrong path.

Comment: "The formula above works perfectly" - I would rather assume the OP knows it is working correctly and there is something left out.

Comment: Test your formula, you will see it does not work, and whether the OP knows it or not neither does the formula they provided.  It will only return the first criteria in the array.